# digitalcoin wallet won't sync

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, windows, altcoin, litecoin-qt

I've had my digitalcoin wallet open for a few days now, hoping it would eventually sync back up but it's seemingly stuck, not necessarily at a specific block, but around 3 days back, whichever block that may be.

I have several other wallets that all sync fine.

Is there something wrong with digitalcoin or is it me?

What would the repair process look like for "resetting" the wallet?

thanks for the help!

Comment: Something similar was happening to me for Dogecoin a couple months ago, was due to a fork on the network and my client having picked up a chain that became the minority one (one of the 3, actually). Since very few miners were working on top of that chain, it'd advance very slowly and then none at all. Suggest you close your clients, delete the last blockchain files and open it again whilst crossing your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you backup your files before doing this!!**

This might be late, but you need to replace the following files in your system.

```
p2pstate.bin
blockchainindices.dat
blockindexes.dat
blocks.dat
blockscache.dat
```

MacOS: `~/.digitalnote`

Linux: `/home/Your username/.digitalnote`

Windows: `C/Windows/Users/Your username/AppData/Roaming/digitalnote`

Here is a video on how to do it for MacOS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QCeQxsZxus