# DigitalNote Wallet Stuck on last node (415608)

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I've downloaded the 1.0.12-beta (last) version of the XDN Wallet from the official website, got the address, transferred 70€-worth of XDN in it using Changelly. The transaction worked fine and I got the confirmation from Changelly.

My wallet has the "not sync issue" that everyone else has ([digitalcoin wallet won't sync](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23062/digitalcoin-wallet-wont-sync)), I tried to fix it by downloading the latest blockchain data and replacing the .dat and .bin files with the ones downloaded, then restarted the wallet.
The wallet started creating the cache, then it blocked showing "Synchronizing 415608/415608".
The digitalnotewallet.log's last lines shows the following error:

```
[node_server] Failed to connect to any of seed peers, continuing without seeds
```

So I'm stuck again without my updated balance.

Is there any way to access my wallet online using my private key, as can be done using a file with MyEtherWallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **No.**

MyEtherWallet relies upon *someone else* running a node whither you connect from the browser in which you're running MyEtherWallet. The problem you've encountered with XDM is that you can't find *someone else* who's running a node, so an XDM version of MyEtherWallet wouldn't help you, even if it existed.

I've never heard of XDM, but if you mean XDN, then the problem is likely to be that there's nobody left who's still running a node at any of the hard-coded seed node IP addresses. If that's correct, then you need to get hold of a *current* list of nodes from a person who's still running one. This is a plausible workaround for the mythical XDM as well as for XDN.

Incidentally, you don't “*access my* [your] *wallet online using my* [your] *private key*”. Your private key is for signing transactions. You do need access to an up-to-date blockchain to *construct* a transaction reliably, but the process of *signing* a transaction (with your private key) does **not** require access to the internet.

Also, if you're holding XDN, you might want to read [this link](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/which-entities-are-related-to-bytecoin-and-minergate) as part of your due diligence, and if you want to explorer the deeper parts of the rabbit warren, there are [more links here](https://np.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6ud6wh/the_strange_birth_history_of_monero_4_part_series/).

Comment: TEV, thank you so much for your answer, I'm sorry for the misspelled acronym, I edited my question with the right one (XDN). To try to solve my issue, as you said `you need to get hold of a current list of nodes from a person who's still running one`, do you have anything in mind that may help me find this person (is there a list somewhere or should I just try to find info in a IRC chan)?

Comment: It looks as if @matt-goll has provided a current list of nodes in his `p2pstate.bin` file  — see [his answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/59273/58807).

Comment: I accepted your answer because you actually answered my question, even if the actual issue was solved by Matt. Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

I hope it helps you, but the current version should fix that. 
https://github.com/xdn-project/digitalnotewallet/releases

If this does not help, can try to change the p2pstate.bin file, 
located in 
C/Windows/Users/Your username/AppData/Roaming/digitalnote
with the file from this one
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4t0S1ES9L-RUUUzX2ZjUW5Xems
and should not help it all, say something!
And if needed, the current addresses should be:

176.9.2.145:8480, 
73.187.10.116:42080, 
176.9.147.178:8480,
148.251.51.113:8480,
122.173.153.251:42080

Best regards

Comment: Thank you very much @Matt, I've upgraded the GUI to the .13 version and replaced the p2pstate.bin file and it started synchronizing. `2017-Sep-08 10:08:40.113286 INFO [protocol] [148.251.51.113:8480 OUT] Sync data returned unknown top block: 415607 -> 425457 [9850 blocks (27 days) behind] 
2017-Sep-08 10:08:40.113286 INFO [protocol] SYNCHRONIZATION started`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=_QCeQxsZxus) on how to fix the syncing issue. Basically, you need to replace the blockchain files with a new set, then restart the syncing. The video has some details on how to do it, but really you need to just replace these files:

```
cd ~/.digitalnote
p2pstate.bin
blockchainindices.dat
blockindexes.dat
blocks.dat
blockscache.dat
```

You can grab new copies of the files [here](https://kickinespresso.com/posts/fixing-the-digital-note-wallet-1-0-12-on-macos-os-x?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=response).